# PHP Error : Use of undefined constant _LINE_ - assumed '_LINE_'

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to develop the online examination system using php and mysql..PLease help me to discover the solution of those problem and why it happen ?, i am really screwed up ! here is my full coding.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM 'questions'
            WHERE question_number = $number";

//Get result 
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die ($mysqli->error._LINE_);
$question = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: Just remove `_LINE_` from this code `$mysqli->error._LINE_`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `_LINE_` from `$mysqli->error._LINE_`.

Now your code will look like

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM 'questions' WHERE question_number = $number";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die ($mysqli->error);
$question = $result->fetch_assoc();
```